# sql server 2005 for windows 7

Tags: sql-server, sql

every time i try to install sql server 2005 on windows 7 it tells me error during installation
error 1603 installing  Microsoft sql server setup support file see log file file for more detailed information
fatal error during the installation and setup terminates 
please advise me to fix this problem

Comment: Why not just use SQL Server 2008?

Comment: try this question here: http://serverfault.com/ they deal more with this type of question than here on stackoverflow

Comment: What's in the error log?

Comment: I got this version to install just fine on two 64bit boxes. After the install you have to run sp3 and the successive CU in order to use it. It will correct the problems about user privilege, user provisioning tool, if I remember correctly

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue where, if you already had .NET 2.0 SP1 installed, the 2005 installer would break.

Wow ... This is a dead question.  Oh, well.

Answer (score 0):

The installer for SQL2005 and for SQL 2008 both warn that there are compatibility issues with the software on windows 7.  I have SQL 2008 installed (64-bit) on a windows 7 box and it runs fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you can either look at or include the output from the setup logs it would help - summary log should be location in the following location (default location, if you chose to install elsewhere it would be located there instead):

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\LOG

There will be a single txt file called "summary.txt" that you will want to inspect/include here first (likely the error exception will be close to the bottom). That will likely point to a problem in a sub-component installation that will have a log file located in the "files" subdirectory below the path above. Anything you can include would help us help you...